# How are data members stored in an object?

Tags: objective-c

I know that in Objective C, every object has first 4 bytes [depending upon type of processor ] as an isa pointer stored in it that tells which class it belongs to and what dispatch table to use to resolve a selector to address of a function.

What I wanted to know was , how are data members stored and accessed in these methods.
self is passed as an implicit object in each function being called.

We use setters n getters to handle data members in other member function as a good practice,

but when we directly refer to a data member in an initializer or an accesor, how are they accessed. Are they replaced by some address at compile time or something else ?

Comment: Apparently, the Objective-C runtime (or some part / version thereof) is open-source. You can look at how the runtime API for getting / setting ivars is implemented here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-class.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually afaik the memory layout is implementation specific, but http://algorithm.com.au/downloads/talks/objective-c-internals/objective-c-internals.pdf should give you a pretty good idea of the inner works of object data and object messaging.

When you use a direct member access, what basically happens is that you're fetching straight from the "struct" that is your actual object. That is, the compiler is basically just adding an offset to the address of your object/struct and reading the contents of that memory address.

Maybe I should add that this is reverse engineered from XCode and not written in any specification I can find, so depending on this behavior is most likely a bad idea. Since external access to the iVars is not allowed, the decision is basically up to the compiler and could be changed at any time.

Edit: as @FrederickCheung points out, Objective C 2.0 may have changed this behavior.

Comment: That's a good presentation and I was thinking of recommending it but I don't think it answers the question. What I get from that presentation is that an object is held as a `struct` (my thinking is oversimplified of course), but how does `myVar = 2;` know it's setting the struct's member `myVar`?

Comment: @Paul.s What *exactly* happens is probably implementation-specific, and hard to determine unless you can read decompiled assembly language. It stands to reason that if object instances are represented as (pointers to) structs at runtime with ivars corresponding to fields, an assignment to an ivar will, at some point, result in an assignment to the corresponding field – since you can access the public ones that way in C code.

Comment: @Paul.s The official docs don't really elaborate on this, they merely state that ivars are accessible in instance method definitions: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-88468

Comment: Nice thanks for that @Inerdial I was starting to think it was something I should know about but it does seem pretty opaque now.

Comment: alot is implementation specific..but in my case only one implementation matters.

Comment: by the way.. this presentation is really awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not as simple as a compile time offset calculation, at least not in objective C 2.0 on the 64bit OS X and iOS runtimes. These support stuff like superclasses changing their instance variable layout without breaking subclasses that were compiled against the old layout by adding a layer of indirection.

The runtime [api docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_setIvar) describe the API one can use to set instance variables and so on but doesn't elaborate on their implementation.